# How can the contract move funds from a user wallet to a contract address

Tags: ether, oracles, sendsignedtransaction

We are creating a system where every month some ethers shall be transferred from user wallet to a contract wallet. We are focusing on creating a dapp too, so a user will initiate this request and once the request is initiated, the ethers will be moved from that user wallet every month (some percentage) to the contract address until the target is reached.

For scheduling, I am thinking of using oraclize, but I'm unsure how to move ethers from user to contract. Is there any approval mechanism for ethers movement too?

Thanks for reading the question, I really appreciate the time you spent

Answer (score 1):

You can't, since only owner of ether have the private keys and able to sign transaction, the only way is to get user's private keys. Nobody will give you the private keys.

You can for example create a holder address, user send a deposit to address you own and after that you able to sent some ether from that address.